# running bundle causing endless loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bundle, bundler

when I ran `bundle -v` or `bundle install` I got a endless looping and memory leak . Here is a

`ps -aux` result

```
li        9082  3.6  0.1  57340 14748 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/bundle -v
li        9084  0.0  0.0   4444   624 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9085  3.7  0.1  54700 14184 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9087  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9088  3.5  0.1  54740 14184 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9090  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9091  3.5  0.1  54644 14092 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9093  0.0  0.0   4444   624 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9094  3.5  0.1  54704 14192 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9096  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9097  3.5  0.1  54716 14204 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9099  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9100  3.5  0.1  54656 14204 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9102  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9103  5.3  0.1  54724 14232 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9105  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9106  5.0  0.1  54732 14216 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9108  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9109  4.6  0.1  54680 14244 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9111  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9112  4.6  0.1  54772 14264 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9114  0.0  0.0   4444   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9115  5.0  0.1  54704 14276 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9117  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9118  4.6  0.1  54796 14100 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9120  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9121  5.0  0.1  54724 14280 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9123  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9124  7.0  0.1  54804 14248 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9126  0.0  0.0   4448   632 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9127  7.0  0.1  54824 14296 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9129  0.0  0.0   4448   632 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9130  7.5  0.1  54704 14304 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9132  0.0  0.0   4448   632 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9133  8.0  0.1  54828 14264 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9135  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9136  7.5  0.1  54824 14308 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9138  0.0  0.0   4448   632 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9139  7.0  0.1  54728 14308 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9141  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9142 15.0  0.1  54844 14312 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9144  0.0  0.0   4448   632 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9145 14.0  0.1  54808 14340 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9147  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9148 15.0  0.1  54860 14332 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9150  0.0  0.0   4448   632 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9151 14.0  0.1  54868 14344 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9153  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9154 14.0  0.1  54876 14308 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9156  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9157 14.0  0.1  54852 14368 pts/7    Sl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9159  0.0  0.0   4448   628 pts/7    S+   07:43   0:00 sh -c /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1
li        9160  0.0  0.0  35972  7640 pts/7    Rl+  07:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
li        9162  0.0  0.0  22644  1332 pts/9    R+   07:43   0:00 ps -axu
```

If I don't terminate the process the list will go on forever until running out of memory.

what is going on here?

`gem list | grep bundler` I got  bundler (1.5.3)

ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: What does `gem list | grep "bundler"` show?

Comment: same version of bundler here... no problems. What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: same version of ruby as well - no problems. I wonder what's going on.

Comment: Maybe give a shot gem install bundler --pre

Comment: @methyl updated to bundler (1.6.0.rc). It is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purged ruby and reinstalled ruby to fix it